# AWS JAVA IoT client reconnects every 10 minutes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, reconnect

I use IoT SDK in JAVA. When my application starts, it connects to IoT core of AWS:

```
iotClient = new AWSIotMqttClient(. . .);            
iotClient.connect();
```

But after application starting I see in my log a very strange behavior and it happens every 10 minutes:

```
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection.onConnectionSuccess Connection successfully established
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient.onConnectionSuccess Client connection active: <client ID>
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection.onConnectionFailure Connection temporarily lost
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient.onConnectionFailure Client connection lost: <client ID>
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection$1.run Connection is being retried
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection.onConnectionSuccess Connection successfully established
[pool-8-thread-1] com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient.onConnectionSuccess Client connection active: <client ID>
```

How can I disable reconnection every 10 minutes? I use IoT Rules on CONNECTED/DISCONNECTED topic, so reconnection every 10 minutes fires this rule every 10 minutes...

Comment: Every 10mins sounds like it may be something at the network level clearing out long term connections. Look at the network your system is running on.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What exactly do I need to check? Thanks

Comment: You need to talk to your network administrator to see if the router/firewall has rules about dropping connections that have no traffic after a certain time limit.

Comment: I use raspberry PI with default FW - ufw.

Comment: That may be where the code it running, but that will not how your site/location is connected to the actual internet

Comment: I disabled FW. It didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, only on my EKS Kubernetes Cluster, but not on my local dev computer.
I found out that the Default keepalive interval of the java lib is 600000ms or 10 minutes. This is not what some documentation declared.

The NAT used on my cluster has a fix Idle Timeout of 350 seconds. So the connection would drop.

I changed it to a lower value (like 30000ms).

```
iotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(30000);
```

For now this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it is my solution:

```
iotClient = new AWSIotMqttClient(. . .);    
        
iotClient.setKeepAliveInterval(0);

iotClient.connect();
```